# set perspective camera as subscene camera in fxml file

Tags: javafx, fxml, javafx-3d

In this code I have a `Subscene` with 3d features enabled. I add camera and meshviews at runtime, but I want to put the camera in FXML because I don´t need to change it at runtime. How can I do that
?

```
<SubScene fx:id="viewer3d" depthBuffer="true" fill="#3389de" height="600.0" width="600.0">
    <root>
        <Region />
    </root>
    <antiAliasing>
    <SceneAntialiasing fx:constant="BALANCED" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with the `fixedEyeAtCameraZero` property being false then all you need is:

```xml
<camera>
  <!-- make sure to import the class (or use fully qualified name) -->
  <PerspectiveCamera/>
</camera>
```

Nested in the `SubScene` element.

However, if you want the aforementioned property to be true then unfortunately you have to write some code. Said property can only be set during construction, but [the constructor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/PerspectiveCamera.html#%3Cinit%3E(boolean)) does not annotate its parameter with `@NamedArg`. Meaning the following:

```xml
<camera>
  <PerspectiveCamera fixedEyeAtCameraZero="true"/>
</camera>
```

Will fail because the `FXMLLoader` will not know what to do with the attribute. In this case, there are two options:

1. Instead of defining the camera in the FXML file, create the camera and set it on the sub-scene in code (e.g., in the controllers `initialize` method).

   I find this option preferable, but that is just my opinion.
2. Continue defining the camera in the FXML file and implement a `Builder` and `BuilderFactory`.

   Here is an example implementation. Note the example `Builder` is extremely simple. It is only implemented to allow setting the `fixedEyeAtCameraZero` property. Trying to set any other property, *which would have otherwise worked without registering this builder*, will now fail. You can add other getters and setters as needed. Or, perhaps easier, you could have the builder implement `Map<String, Object>` and appropriately implement the `put` method.

   **Builder**

   ```
   import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
   import javafx.util.Builder;

   public class PerspectiveCameraBuilder implements Builder<PerspectiveCamera> {

     private boolean fixedEyeAtCameraZero;

     public boolean isFixedEyeAtCameraZero() {
       return fixedEyeAtCameraZero;
     }

     public void setFixedEyeAtCameraZero(boolean fixedEyeAtCameraZero) {
       this.fixedEyeAtCameraZero = fixedEyeAtCameraZero;
     }

     @Override
     public PerspectiveCamera build() {
       return new PerspectiveCamera(fixedEyeAtCameraZero);
     }
   }
   ```

   **Builder Factory**

   ```java
   import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
   import javafx.util.Builder;
   import javafx.util.BuilderFactory;

   public class MyBuilderFactory implements BuilderFactory {

     @Override
     public Builder<?> getBuilder(Class<?> type) {
       if (type == PerspectiveCamera.class) {
         return new PerspectiveCameraBuilder();
       }
       return null;
     }
   }
   ```

   **Usage**

   ```java
   var loader = new FXMLLoader(...);
   loader.setBuilderFactory(new MyBuilderFactory());
   // ... load FXML file
   ```